# jQuery AJAX initial data problem for dynamic dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, initialization

I have a problem with initialization of dynamically filled dropdowns in jQuery.
Basically, I have function `fillCityList` and it makes AJAX call to fill the cities by the passing country.
Because this is used in `Edit` form, I have a default `City` value in `id_cityHidden` field.
Actually the code below works well.However, because `fillCityList` takes long time to fill the city list, while default city is selected, the city list may not be ready.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    fillCityList(1);
    $('#city').val($("#id_cityHidden").val());  
});
```

I know there is a solution like "call function at `complete` stage of AJAX call" but I just need it during initialization.
One solution might be setting a `timeout` or `delay` between `fillCityList` and 
`$('#city').val($("#id_cityHidden").val())` however, it is not a good solution of course.

What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you build your ajax to use the 'complete' function, then update the value.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: thanks for your reply but as I said it may not be a good solution because when an error happened in the form it may result in crash. However, if it is the only way to do this, I am going to apply it..

Comment: if you think it will throw errors, use a try{//code}catch(error){//try to fix error}